# Calculating Android app hash key for one time SMS codes

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

I implemented the functionality to automatically retrieve a one time code via SMS on Android. I added the app hash key to the end of the text message as recommended on https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2019/03/09/using-sms-retriever-api-in-xamarin-android/.

I'm retrieving the app hash key via [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/UdaraAlwis/c83ebd573d262552b5bd0836058be58b#file-apphashkeyhelper-cs). I calculated the hash key once and hard-coded it on the server side. Recently, I realized one time codes no longer work and this is because the app hash key has changed. I'm not sure what led to this. I re-calculated it with the same implementation and things are working now.

My question is, how should this be handled in production? Should app hash keys be calculated each time an SMS is sent out? I was under the impression that this key would never change once calculated, so at this point I'm not sure if hard-coding it on the server side is a good idea.

Comment: Did you change the keystore you are using to sign the App with? If so, the hash-key probably changes.

Comment: Not sure about this. The app is still in development. I haven't gone to production yet. In production, do we get only one hash key that does not change throughout the lifetime of the app? I can't decide if this should be hardcoded on the server or not.

Comment: The keystore for a production app should not change no. However, it could change while developing depending on the debug.keystore used.